# web scraping using request showing empty tables?

Tags: python, django

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-17/31908/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tables = tree.xpath('//table/text()')
print(tables)
```

here i wants to get all the table from above url.
But it is coming empty list wheather many tables are available 
in web page.

Comment: I get `['\n', '\n', '\n        ', '\n']`, which is logical, since `text()` only shows the text nodes at that specific level.

Comment: i am also getting same instead of tables..

Comment: Well that's logical, since `/text()` does not select tables, it select the text nodes just undeneath the `table` tags.

Comment: then, how can i get TABLES

Comment: By simply `tree.xpath('//table')`

Comment: its giving  [<Element table at 0x7f0fb1cd9208>, <Element table at 0x7f0fb1cf3d60>]

Comment: ya its working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample code I created and tested that will print the tables to an html file that you can open in the browser.

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-17/31908/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tables = tree.cssselect('table')

file = open("output.html","wb") 

for table in tables:
    file.write(etree.tostring(table))
```